# Require minimum version of R package

Tags: r, version, package

I just noticed that there's no `version` argument to `R`'s `require()` or `library()` functions.  What do people do when they need to ensure they have at least some minimum version of a package, so that e.g. they know some bug is fixed, or some feature is available, or whatever?

I'm aware of the `Depends` stuff for package authors, but I'm looking for something to use in scripts, interactive environments, `org-mode` files, code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not aware of such a function, but it should be quite easy to make one. You can base it on `sessionInfo()` or `packageVersion()`. After loading the packages required for the script, you can harvest the package numbers from there. A function that checks the version number would look like (in pseudo code, as I don't have time right now):

```
check_version = function(pkg_name, min_version) {
    cur_version = packageVersion(pkg_name)
    if(cur_version < min_version) stop(sprintf("Package %s needs a newer version, 
               found %s, need at least %s", pkg_name, cur_version, min_version))
}
```

Calling it would be like:

```
library(ggplot2)
check_version("ggplot2", "0.8-9")
```

You still need to parse the version numbers into something that allows the comparison `cur_version < min_version`, but the basic structure remains the same.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like `compareVersion()` is the right thing to use for version comparison.

Comment: Awesome that function was there, tried to make something myself, but that wasnt needed :).

Comment: @KenWilliams -- Nice catch. I had a look at it, and was thrown off track by its help-page statement that "R package version numbers are of the form ‘x.y-z’". But it looks like in reality it `strsplit()`s on both `"-"` and `"."`, so that detail doesn't matter.

Comment: It's a bit buried, but the docs for `package_version` say:  "Numeric versions are sequences of one or more non-negative integers, usually (e.g., in package ‘DESCRIPTION’ files) represented as character strings with the elements of the sequence concatenated and separated by single . or - characters. **R package versions** consist of at least two such integers, an R system version of exactly three (major, minor and patchlevel)."

Answer (score 20):

You could use `packageVersion()`:

```
packageVersion("stats")
# [1] ‘2.14.1’

if(packageVersion("stats") < "2.15.0") {
    stop("Need to wait until package:stats 2.15 is released!")
}
# Error: Need to wait until package:stats 2.15 is released!
```

This works because `packageVersion()` returns an object of class `package_version` for which `<` behaves as we'd like it to (which `<` will not do when comparing two character strings using their lexicographical ordering).

Answer (score 13):

After reading Paul's pseudocode, here's the function I've written.

```
use <- function(package, version=0, ...) {
  package <- as.character(substitute(package))
  library(package, ..., character.only=TRUE)
  pver <- packageVersion(package)
  if (compareVersion(as.character(pver), as.character(version)) < 0)
    stop("Version ", version, " of '", package, 
         "' required, but only ", pver, " is available")
  invisible(pver)
}
```

It functions basically the same as `library()`, but takes an extra `version` argument:

```
> use(plyr, 1.6)
> use(ggplot2, '0.9')
Error in use(ggplot2, "0.9") : 
  Version 0.9 of 'ggplot2' required, but only 0.8.9 is available
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pacman`-package provides the `p_install_version` function that allows to define a minimal package version.

For a single package:

```r
pacman::p_install_version(
  'conflicted',  # the package
  '1.2.0'        # the minimum version to be installed
)
```

Or multiple packages at once:

```r
pacman::p_install_version(
  c('conflicted', 'tidyverse'),
  c('1.2.0', '2.0.0')
)
```

Note that the packages are only installed and have to be loaded afterwards:

```r
pacman::p_load(
  conflicted, tidyverse
)
```